# nginx reverse proxy not finding backend service in docker-comopse

Tags: docker, nginx, networking, docker-compose, containers

I have the following `docker-compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  webapp:
    image: example/webapp
    build:
      context: app
    restart: always
    ports:
      - ":8181"
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
    volumes:
      - secret-store:/app/data
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - bridged_network

  nginx:
    image: example/reverseproxy
    build:
      context: reverseproxy
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    depends_on:
      - webapp

networks:
  bridged_network:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  secret-store:
```

The `nginx` image is being built as follows

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/*
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Where `nginx.conf`

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://webapp:8181;
  }
}
```

However in the `nginx` container logs:

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "webapp" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:6
```

Why is `nginx` failing to discover `webapp` service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your nginx reverse proxy in the same network as the service?
It looks like they are not in the same network.

Comment: ...the easiest way to resolve this is to delete all of the `networks:` options in the entire file.  Compose will create a network named `default` and attach both containers to it.